# Export paper bibliography Zotero

Tags: python, api, reference, export, bibliography

I am trying to get one paper's bibliography using Zotero.

This means that, given one paper (for example, [On the Parameter Estimation in the Schwartz-Smith’s Two-Factor Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.01881.pdf)), I need a file (excel, csv, ...) containing all the papers which were cited in the given paper (e.g.,  *1. Ames, M., Bagnarosa, G., Matsui, T., Peters, G., Shevchenko, P.V.: Which risk factors drive oil futures price curves? Available at SSRN 2840730 (2016)
2. Binkowski, K., Shevchenko, P., Kordzakhia, N.: Modelling of commodity prices
(2009), CSIRO technical report, ...*).

How can I achieve that? I am trying with `Zotero API` and `Zotero export settings`, but I am not able to retrieve the desired result.

Available (incomplete because of output errors) code:

```
from pprint import pprint
from pyzolocal.sqls import gets as g
pprint(g.get_attachments())
```